# How to download JSON data in android

Tags: java, android, json, service, web

I am developing an android application in which first I am sending request to Web service and getting the response status in 0 or 1 format if I get the response as 1 then complete JSON file is loaded.
My question is I want to make an offline app for which I want to download the JSON data from one activity and read that data in different activity with listview displaying title of every downloaded JSON file. After clicking the listview item, JSON data is displayed. And some of the JSON data items contains URL of images I also want to download them and display them in another activity.
I also want to encrypt the downloaded JSON data. Please Help me.

For reference I have attached the JSON file format.

> {"test_time":7200,"time_taken":"0","time_left":"7200","score":null,"easy_score":null,"medium_score":null,"hard_score":null,"status":"n","sections":[{"section_id":"196498","section_name":"Reasoning Aptitude","section_no":1,"total_questions":"40","total_minutes":"24","questions":[{"question_id":"61562","question":{"1":{"text":"In a certain code GRANT is written as UOBSH and PRIDE is written as FEJSQ. How is SOLD written in that code?","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}},"correct_ans":{"1":{"text":"EMPT","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}},"rightOption":[],"rightOptionID":"246408","rightOptionNo":"2","anwer_explaination":{"1":{"text":"","image":"http://abc.com/testengine/images/questions/bankpower/image1.Jpeg","imgHeight":304,"imgWidth":212},"2":{"text":"  ","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}},"question_time_taken":"10","marked":"0","skipped":"0","answer_id":"1395795","option_choose":"246407","question_status":1,"options":[{"OptionId":"246406","OptionDesc":{"1":{"text":"EPMT","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}}},{"OptionId":"246407","OptionDesc":{"1":{"text":"TPME","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}}},{"OptionId":"246408","OptionDesc":{"1":{"text":"EMPT","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}}},{"OptionId":"246409","OptionDesc":{"1":{"text":"CKNR","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}}},{"OptionId":"246410","OptionDesc":{"1":{"text":"ETPM","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}}}]},{"question_id":"61563","question":{"1":{"text":"Four of the following five are alike in a certain way and so form a group. Which is the one that does not belong to that group?","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}},"correct_ans":{"1":{"text":"27","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}},"rightOption":[],"rightOptionID":"246414","rightOptionNo":"3","anwer_explaination":{"1":{"text":"Mouse is odd rest are use for storage.","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}},"question_time_taken":"0","marked":"0","skipped":"1","answer_id":"","option_choose":"","question_status":3,"options":[{"OptionId":"246411","OptionDesc":{"1":{"text":"19","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}}},{"OptionId":"246412","OptionDesc":{"1":{"text":"17","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}}},{"OptionId":"246413","OptionDesc":{"1":{"text":"13","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}}},{"OptionId":"246414","OptionDesc":{"1":{"text":"27","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}}},{"OptionId":"246415","OptionDesc":{"1":{"text":"37","image":"","imgHeight":"","imgWidth":""}}}]}

Comment: you need to make a http request to the url and get the data first check if its a valid json here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: JSON is just like any other text string; you download it like you would anything else. And please, please use the backtick (`) to format your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parse all the data using the parser detailed in that link

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
 then Write all the data into a file using the method below  , this way ur data is downloaded and saved as a file

```
public void appendData(String text)
{       
    File myFile = new File("sdcard/myfile.file");
    if (!myFile.exists())
    {
      try
      {
          myFile.createNewFile();
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  try
  {
      //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile, true)); 
      buf.append(text);
      buf.newLine();
      buf.close();
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: But JSON file contains some URL of images and I want to download those images also and then read the downloaded JSON file with either text or  images. If I download the JSON file then it will contain the URL of image but for offline use I want to change that URL with the path of those images which are downloaded from those URL and save to sdcard. Please help to implement it.

Comment: when u parse the data , u have load  convert the images into bitmap, and then save the files into sd card , and maintain a database containing the path of the images in the sd card ,.

Comment: afterwards , when u are offline , match the id to databae , and load specific images to ur application from sd card.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
   private class PrepareMapTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
    {
        // Initialize with invalid value
        private int mPrepareResult = -1;
        private String mJsonString = null;

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            mJsonString = downloadFileFromInternet(urls[0]);
            if(mJsonString == null /*|| mJsonString.isEmpty()*/)
                return false;

            JSONObject jObject = null;
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(mJsonString);
                JSONArray jsonImageArray = jObject.getJSONArray("imageTarget");
                JSONArray jsonUrlArray = jObject.getJSONArray("videoUrls");
                JSONArray jsonVideoOrUrlArray = jObject.getJSONArray("videoOrUrl");
                if (jsonImageArray == null || jsonUrlArray == null)
                    return false;
                for (int i = 0; i<jsonImageArray.length(); i++){ 
                    mapTargetUrl.put(jsonImageArray.get(i).toString(), jsonUrlArray.get(i).toString());
                    mVideoOrUrl.add(jsonVideoOrUrlArray.get(i).toString());
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {
        }

        private String downloadFileFromInternet(String url)
        {
            if(url == null /*|| url.isEmpty() == true*/)
                new IllegalArgumentException("url is empty/null");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream inStream = null;
            try
            {
                url = urlEncode(url);
                URL link = new URL(url);
                inStream = link.openStream();
                int i;
                int total = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                while((i=inStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    if(total >= (1024 * 1024))
                    {
                        return "";
                    }
                    total += i;
                    sb.append(new String(buffer,0,i));
                }
            }catch(Exception e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private String urlEncode(String url)
        {
            if(url == null /*|| url.isEmpty() == true*/)
                return null;
            url = url.replace("[","");
            url = url.replace("]","");
            url = url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
            return url;
        }

    }
```

Take the data structures as per your json and modify the code.

Comment: don't forget the `inStream.close();`

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

                  DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);


        // Set HTTP parameters
        /*StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());*/
        jsonObjSend.length();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(jsonObjSend.length());
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", jsonObjSend.toString()));
       // Log.i("jsonObjSend.toString()","jsonObjSend.toString()"+jsonObjSend.toString());

        Log.i("HTTPPOST","URL: "+URL);
        Log.i("HTTPPOST","Request: "+jsonObjSend.toString());
        UrlEncodedFormEntity en=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
        en.getContent();
        httpPostRequest.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(600000));
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(en);
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");
        Log.i(TAG, httpPostRequest.getRequestLine().getProtocolVersion().toString());
        responses = convertEntityToString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        Log.i("HTTPPOST","Responce: "+responses);
        Log.i("HTTPPOST","******************");
        //Log.i("Encoding",response.getEntity().getContentEncoding().getName());



                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    webresponse = 1;
                } else {
                    webresponse = 0;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                h.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        AlertNullWebserviceResponce();

                    }
                });

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: `DefaultHttpClient` is less stable than `HttpURLConnection` since Gingerbread